# Web Automation using C#

Tags: c#, webautomation

I'm automating a web page using c#. I am able to access a drop down using its ID. But I am not able to do a post back,which prevents other drop downs from auto loading.

I am using HTMLDocument and IHTMLElement objects to access elements in web page.

```
document = (HTMLDocument)IEInstance.Document;
IHTMLElement element1 = document.getElementById("ID");
element1.setAttribute("value", "VALUE");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use selenium in your project (its special opensource project for web automation)

[SELENIUM WEBSITE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)